# Heart rate sensor API for Android

Tags: android, wear-os

Google has published apis with respect to wearable devices. Since many smart watch manufactures state they have a heart rate sensor, I'm wondering if android published apis for it. I checked the web and didn't find anything.

Anyone who's interested in wearable developing that happens to know about it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(As of now) those APIs belong to each smartwatch maker not Google.
Please check my project here:

http://blog.kii.com/?p=3942

and specifically this file:

https://github.com/germanviscuso/PingHeart/blob/master/wear/src/main/java/com/kii/demo/wearable/WearActivity.java

to see how to use the heart rate sensor API on the Samsung Gear Live.

Best.

German

Comment: If the answer works for you can you flag it as the correct answer please?

Comment: Hi German, can you tell me how long does it take to respond? is it good for getting live heart rate for few minutes?

Comment: It can take up to 30 secs to get a fix, depends a lot on whether there's good contact of the sensor with the skin (sometimes it's not the case). Once you get a fix you can take the readings for a short time, probably a minute (to be honest I haven't tried more time). IMHO it's not going to be good to sustain a live reading for a few minutes, it's for occasional use. Good luck

Comment: This answer is now 5 years old. What is the situation as of 2019?