# Transfer heart rate from smart watch to Android mobile

Tags: android, mobile, tizen, android-wear-data-api, android-wear-2.0

I would like to send my heart rate measured by SmartWatch to Android mobile.
And I want to send that heart rate information to someone else's cell phone.
(For example, when a grandfather who wears a wearable suddenly falls down, I want the information to go to his guardian.)

①Smart Watch → ②My Cell Phone → ③(only when it is dangerous) Protector's cell phone

---

In my country, however, there was only one book published in 2014 on smart watch development, and no way to transmit heart rate information to mobile. related information were available on the Tizen and Stack Overflowhomepage, but I do not know how to develop it.

rink (1)
[Get data from Smartwatch Android Wear to Smartphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27388443/get-data-from-smartwatch-android-wear-to-smartphone)

rink (2)
[How to get raw data(Heart Rate etc) from samsung gear s3 in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43606219/how-to-get-raw-dataheart-rate-etc-from-samsung-gear-s3-in-android)

rink (3)
https://developer.tizen.org/zh-hans/forums/native-application-development/%EA%B8%B0%EC%96%B4s%EC%99%80-%EC%95%88%EB%93%9C%EB%A1%9C%EC%9D%B4%EB%93%9C-%EA%B0%92-%EC%A0%84%EB%8B%AC%EC%97%90-%EB%8C%80%ED%95%B4%EC%84%9C...?langswitch=zh-hans

rink (4)
[Heart rate sensor API for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25896481/heart-rate-sensor-api-for-android)

rink (5)
https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/accessing-heart-rate-monitor-hrm-sensor-data-native-applications?langswitch=en

---

---

On the Android Developers home page, there was data transmission.
Can I use this to transfer my heart rate information to mobile?
https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/assets.html

I am new to Android studio development and wearable development, and I do not know how to make it. 
I would like to ask if there is any tutorial related to SmartWatch heart rate transmission.

I have been looking at the Github source once, but I'm not sure it is right to do this.
https://github.com/dirkvranckaert/HeartRateMonitor

https://github.com/alejandrocq/HeartRateTest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[#1] Smart Watch

To fetch heart rate data from sensor you have to develop a Tizen UI/service application. In that Tizen application, you have fetch data using Sensor/Human Activity Monitor API. You can chose either Tizen Native API for Native app (C/C++) or Tizen Web API for Web app (HTML/CSS/JS).

Guides:

Web API

[Human Activity Monitor Guide](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/sensors/human-activity-monitor)

[Human activity monitor API References](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/web-application?redirect=/dev-guide/2.3.1/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/wearable/tizen/humanactivitymonitor.html)

or Native API

[Device Sensors Guide](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/native-application/location-and-sensors/device-sensors)

[Device Sensors API References](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.3.2/org.tizen.native.wearable.apireference/group__CAPI__SYSTEM__SENSOR__MODULE.html)

Or If you move to Android wear than check out the [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/building-wearables.html).

[#2] Smart Watch to My Cell Phone

For connection and data transfer between mobile android device and Samsung Gear device , Accessory Protocol is defined. So, the option available here is using Accessory SDK for Android mobile and Tizen wearable.

[Samsung Accessory SDK](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/accessory)

You may check my response on similar issue on this post, the difference is just 'step count' instead 'heart rate'

[How to integrate Samsung Gear Steps in android Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40233692/how-to-integrate-samsung-gear-steps-in-android-application/40529913#40529913)

[#3] My Cell Phone to Protectors Cell Phone

You may check this post on SO:

[Android - communicating between two devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608832/android-communicating-between-two-devices)

Obviously bluetooth won't be a solution for this case, you may check the documentations on Web socket on the post above. You may think of HTTP request-response also.